# Is it possible to build Android Automotive apps using common UI layouts like those for mobile phones?

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

I'm talking about the usual ConstraintLayout or LinearLayout from Android development for mobile phones. Is it possible or allowed to create and install an app built like this on the Android Automotive OS (not Android Auto)?
If the answer is yes, do you have any documentation regarding this or project examples/samples?

Publishing the app on the Automotive Store is not important for me, Google wouldn't allow this anyway. I just want to be able to create a very custom app for me or a possible OEM.
I know there's an Android for Cars Library but it's not even working for AAOS at this moment, only for Android Auto.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create and install normal Android apps that use common layouts on the AAOS Emulator. You may not be able to upload these apps on the store but an OEM probably can install any apps it wants.

Check the 'A Better Routeplanner' app, it was uploaded by Polestar on the AAOS store and it probably uses the UI layouts you mentioned considering how custom and similar it is to the mobile version.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.polestar.abrp.production.android

Comment: Thanks for the answer. you're right, I recently found a lot of AAOS custom apps that couldn't be built without the common layouts. Some of them may have used the Car UI library but it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the user specific case, i.e. Is it going to be using navigation or radio for example.

Comment: I don't plan on implementing navigation or radio, but would that be impossible? could you please elaborate?